# Can allies help pinpoint an invisible enemy's location?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, invisibility

When fighting an invisible enemy (suppose something with natural or Greater Invisibility), if a party caster throws on See Invisibility would they then be able to direct allies to the exact location to avoid the rules pertaining to locating an invisible enemy?

Anyone who couldn't see obviously still wouldn't be able to target the invisible enemy with targeted spells, and would still take the 50% total concealment miss chance, but it helps forgo the long convoluted rules about feeling around in the dark.

Does anything change between Invisibility/See Invisibility or being in darkness without Darkvision and having an Outsider (etc) ally help point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can describe the position of the invisible enemy: *in front of the door*, *at the left side of the queen*, *right next to that tree*, etc. Which should give enough information for many characters to be able to do something about it, like throwing a [Glitterdust](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust/), or charge into that direction using their [scent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Scent-Ex-), or throw an [area spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/entangle/) at them that will prevent their escape.

They can also help with allies's [Perception](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception/) checks to pinpoint an invisible enemy:

> A creature can generally notice the presence of an active invisible creature within 30 feet with a DC 20 Perception check. The observer gains a hunch that “something’s there” but can’t see it or target it accurately with an attack. It’s practically impossible (+20 DC) to pinpoint an invisible creature’s location with a Perception check.

You can tell that this is normally a really hard check, DC 40, but if said invisible creature is not moving at half speed, and if they are active in combat, this can be reduced as low as DC 10 or 20, and an [Aid Another](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Aid-Another) check would actually be helpful.